# ember.js: using `needs`, in one controller needlessly reinitializes sibling controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have Controller A, which has its `needs` property set to `['controllerB']`. Controller B is initialized with and assigned to View B. The view creating and assigning its own controller happens just fine.

In Controller A, I call for `this.get('controllers.controllerA')`. This causes Controller B to *initialize again* (that is, `init` is called again in `Controller B`) presumably with no relation to `View B`). The net result of this is that I"m not able to access any of the values of the form in `View B`.

What am I doing wrong here?

edit -- code example:

```
var ControllerA = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['controllerB'],

  someFunctionThatEventuallyGetsCalled: function() {
    this.get('controllerB'); // initializes new controllerB
  }
});

var ControllerB = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  init: function (){
    // ... called twice; once by view, once by Controller A
  }
});

var ViewB = Em.View.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('controller', ControllerB.create());
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by initialized? Like the `init` function is called again?

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide some code, generally controllers are singleton instances, so I'd be interested to see how you're hooking everything up.  Especially when you said `The view creating and assigning its own controller happens just fine.`

Comment: Code updated provided.

Comment: @dclowd9901 the `needs` property leads to the initialization of `ControllerB` singleton instance and the call of `ControllerB.create()` causes another instance of `ControllerB` to be created. Hence the property values and overall state will not be the same.

Comment: I thought that `needs` just uses the singleton instance that already exists. That explains a lot.

How on earth are you supposed to maintain/access/link multiple controllers on a page?

Comment: I dont think you need to set controller in the viewB, controllerB will be the controller for viewB because of the naming convention that ember follows if there is a resource or route by the name B.

Comment: I'm curious what the goal of this code is.

Comment: The goal of the code was to allow a view to dictate initialization, rather than a route.